# Android Dialog Activity Theme : android:theme vs setTheme()

Tags: java, android, android-activity, dialog, themes

I am trying to set an Activity like a dialog here is my code:

```
public class TetsDialog extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));
    }
}
```

This is what I get with above code.
[image]

But If I add this in activity's manifest entry

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`

I get this:
[image]

So What I want to get is, activity with transparent background like the second image but with only `setTheme()`. Why both of this `android:theme` and `setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dialog)` does not have same result?

There are so many question regarding making a transparent dialog activity(even I found issue on Google code similar to my question but i lost that link) but none of them have any correct answer.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I looked into Android code while ago, and I found that:

- When set theme by in manifest, some properties 'll be use to configure right after activity's contruction and before it's going to add to a window. -> some properties like transparent activity only works by this way.
- While set theme by code, you 'll only can call in `onCreate`, while at that time, activity already finished initial works and was assign to a window( not attached yet) -> so some properties like transparent won't work.

So basically, set theme by xml and by code will return different results. And I think there's no way to pass through it.
Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.